# how to push objects to an array with this structure?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an array of objects as shown below:

```
filters = { color: { red: true, blue: true }, size: { medium: false } };
```

If I want to insert the yellow color.

It should be inserted in color and it would look like this:

```
filters = { color: { red: true, blue: true, yellow: true }, size: { medium: false },price:{} };
```

If I bring a value of type size, insert in size :{small:true}

Can someone please let me know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your filters is not an array but an object. So, insert in the following way.

```js
filters = { color: { red: true, blue: true }, size: { medium: false } };

filters.color['yellow'] = true;

filters.size['small'] = true;

console.log('filters = ', filters);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying that it is an object and not an array.

What I did was to do this:

    arrayg = {color: {}, price: {}, size: {}, gener: {}};

And through a function:
onChange (cat, value, isChecked: boolean) {
     this.arrayg [cat] [value] = isChecked;
    console.log (this.arrayg);
   }

But do you think there is a way to make my arrayg object dynamic?